# Fit data with proportional dependent variable

Tags: r, statistics

Here's a simplified version of my question with example data:

Each year, I find 40 balls in my yard. A certain proportion of them are red. I'd like to model the proportion of red balls over time.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

# generate some proportion data that changes by year
data = tibble(
  year = 2011:2020, 
  reds = 1:10, # red balls
  total = 40, # total number of balls
  propRed = reds / total # proportion of red balls each year
)

# fit to a model
model = glm(propRed ~ year, XXX_WHAT_GOES_HERE_XXX, data)

# graph the model's prediction and the data
tibble(year = 2000:2030) %>% 
  modelr::add_predictions(model, "propRed") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    aes(y=propRed, x=year) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data=data)
```

Comment: this can be a logistic regression. call `glm` using something like `glm(cbind(reds, total - reds) ~ year, family = 'binomial', data = data)`

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Besides, you may want to post in Cross Validated.

Comment: @bouncyball: I ran `tibble(year = 2000:2030) %>% predict.glm(model, .)`, and it predicted negative values which should not be possible.

Comment: @sharoz those predictions are the log-odds ([read the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html)), replace the `add_predictions` line with `mutate(propRed = predict(model, newdata = ., type = 'response'))`

Comment: Thank you! `type = 'response'` is what I needed! If you add that as an answer, I'll give it a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where we can use logistic regression, using the `cbind(successes, failures)` option in the formula interface for `glm`:

```
model <- glm(cbind(reds, total - reds) ~ year, family = 'binomial', data = data)

tibble(year = 2000:2030) %>% 
    mutate(propRed = predict(model, newdata = ., type = 'response')) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    aes(y=propRed, x=year) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data=data)
```